# Limit the number of letter repetition in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have this RegExp:

```js
const pattern = new RegExp('^(test?:\\/\\/)?(aaa\\.)?');
console.log(pattern.test('aaaa')) //expect false
console.log(pattern.test('aaa')) //expect true
```

Here i try to exclude words with more than 3 `a`. So in the first case i expect to get `false`, but i got `true` even if the word has more than 3 `a`. 
 Question: how to get what i expect? 
 PS: i suppose that this happens because of `?` after `aaa`, but i need this to be optional. How to change my code?

Comment: Are you trying to block 3 _continuous_ `a's`, or 3 `a's` anywhere in the input?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, i try to block `aaa` (so more than 3 `a` should be excluded)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to rule out more than 3 (i.e. 4 or more) *continuous* `a` letters, then use the regex pattern `^(?!.*aaaa).*$`:

```js
var input = ["hello world aaa", "goodbye aaaa"];
for (var i=0; i < input.length; ++i) {
    if (/^(?!.*aaaa).*$/.test(input[i])) {
        console.log(input[i] + " => MATCH");
    }
    else {
        console.log(input[i] + " => NO MATCH");
    }
}
```

Comment: but how to keep optional this combination of letters like in my case? Could you show in my code please?